# Getting sfdx error: running AuthLogin: The service and account specified in key.json do not match the version of the toolbelt

Tags: salesforcedx

I am getting this error when running my sfdx plugin in jenkins not sure what it is asking me to do, I have the latest sfdx cli installed?

> ERROR running AuthLogin:  The service and account specified in key.json do not match the version of the toolbelt.
>
> Try this:
>
> Check your toolbelt version and re-auth.

Answer (score 0):

I've just faced the same problem and this approach solved my issue:
Delete the key.json file (on Linux it is in $HOME/.sfdx folder) and try to log again.
More about this issue at here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-core/issues/83

Comment: Hi i can't seem to find the key.json in $HOME/.sfdx folder, is it only available after first login?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to upgrade my auth plugin because of the fix described [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/757).